# How to do a blocking and synchronized activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, synchronous

Well, please don't ask me why, but I need to start a synchronous and blocking activity so that the program flow won't continue until it's finished. I know how to do a synchronous Dialog, but how can I do a synchronous activity?

Following are two approaches I tried but failed:

```
// In the 1st activity, start the 2nd activity in the usual way
startActivity(intent);
Looper.loop();        // but pause the program here
// Program continuse running afer Looper.loop() returns
....

// Then, in the second activity's onBackPressed method:
public void onBackPressed() {
    // I was hoping the following quit() will terminate the loop() call in
    // the first activity. But it caused an exception "Main thread not allowed
    // to quit." Understandable.
    new Hanlder().getLooper().quit();
}
```

I also tried to use another thread to achieve this:

```
// In the first activity, start a thread
SecondThread m2ndThread = new SecondThread(this);
Thread th = new Thread(m2ndThread, "Second Thread");
th.run();
synchronized(m2ndThread) {
    m2ndThread.wait();
}

class SecondThread implements Runnable {

    Activity m1stActivity;

    SecondThread(Activity a) {
        m1stActivity = a;
    }

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        Handler h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(m1stActivity, SecondActivity.class);
                m1stActivity.startActivity(intent); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            }
        }
        h.sendEmptyMessage(10); // let it run
        Looper.quit();
    }
}
```

However, this approach doesn't work because when I'm using the 1st activity to start the 2nd activity, the main thread is already in wait state and doing nothing. So the 2nd activity didn't even get created. (This is ironical: You have to use an activity to start an activity, but how can you do that when it's already in wait state?)

Comment: Can't you just show a ProgressDialog? This will stop the user from being able to interact with your activity while you perform whatever task it is you're doing.

Comment: @dmon, hmmm..., is ProgressDialog blocking? Hmm... Interesting. I sure will give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I mean it wont block the main thread execution, obviously, but you can do your work in the background while the user is left there staring at the awesome spinny thinghy.

Comment: @dmon, ha ha ha, I got it. But that doesn't work for this case. Anyway, I have changed the spec and come up with a pretty nasty work-around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't.

That is all there is to it.  You just can't do this.  Activities execute on the main thread, always.  Your main thread must be actively running its event loop.  It is ALWAYS broken to block the main thread's event loop.  Always.

Comment: a great answer, giving me some more insight of Android. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

All activities are asynchronous. But if you want to block the rest of your application flow until the activity finishes, you can inject a dependency on a flag that the activity sets. The most encapsulated way to do so would be to carry the flag along with the intent/activity/return flow. You could:

Declare the flag in that object's global scope:

```
boolean syncBlock = false;
int ASYNC_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1; // Arbitrary unique int
```

In the object's scope that starts the new activity include:

```
Intent asyncIntent = new Intent(this, AsyncActivity.class);
syncBlock = true;
startActivityForResult(asyncIntent, ASYNC_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
while(syncBlock) {}
```

And in in the object that started the activity:

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  switch(requestCode)
  {
    case ASYNC_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
    {
      syncBlock = false;
      break;
    }

[...]
}
```

It's a crude hack, and if you're blocking in your UI thread (eg. in your MAIN activity) you're blocking everything, including other UI features your users will probably expect to respond but won't. It's a big nono, and you should learn to go with the async flow that makes apps work the Android way. But if you absolutely must...

Comment: While this is crude, it does work!  May I suggest though that rather than using a tight loop (while loop will execute many times) that instead you look at a [CountDownLatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and call await() on the latch after startActivityForResult is called, and countDown() in onActivityResult?

Comment: @BK: Sure, the while loop on the sync lock is badly performant and not entirely safe. And indeed as I mentioned blocking in the UI thread is a bad idea. Implementing a CountDownLatch is better. But if you're going to any further length than the crude blocking I posted, you should probably go a little further and embrace the async in your design rather than double down on the crude blocking hack.

Comment: How correct you are!!  I was quick to point out an optimization, but you are right that adopting async is the way to go. Good call!